# jquery throws-Uncaught TypeError while trying to get image from user to send it to controller via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

> The script works fine without the image tag in html and jquery so i suppose the problem is with uploading the image somehow the variable is not storing the image to send it to controller class, could some one please tell me the reason why and how to fix this, im a newbie try to understand the reason behind things and solutions to gain deeper understanding thanks

```js
load = function(){ 
  var checkedName = document.querySelector('input[name="state-name"]:checked'),
  name = checkedName ? checkedName.value : "Nothing selected";
     var cityname=document.getElementById("R_city").value();
     var info=document.getElementById("R_info").value;
     var profilepic=document.getElementById("pic").value();
      document.write("state name"+ name+ "city name"+cityname+"profile pic"+ profilepic+"basic info"+info);}
          
           data = "";
  
 myfunction = function(){
  alert("hi inside myfunction");
     load();  
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Ontario " value="1" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Ontario "> Ontario </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" checked id=" British Columbia " value="2" />
    <label class="Button" for=" British Columbia "> British Columbia </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Quebec " value="3" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Quebec "> Quebec </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Alberta " value="4" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Alberta "> Alberta </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Nova Scotia " value="5" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Nova Scotia "> Nova Scotia </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Saskatchewan " value="6" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Saskatchewan "> Saskatchewan </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Manitoba " value="7" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Manitoba "> Manitoba </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" New Brunswick " value="8" />
    <label class="Button" for=" New Brunswick "> New Brunswick </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" New founded land " value="9" />
    <label class="Button" for=" New founded land "> New founded land </label>
    <input type="radio" name="state-name" class="ButtonState" id=" Prince Edward Isand " value="10" />
    <label class="Button" for=" Prince Edward Isand "> Prince Edward Isand </label>
  </div>
  <br>
<div> 
<input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="Your city" id="R_city" pattern='[A-Za-z\\s]*' title="Must not contain any numbers or special characters" required /><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:36px"></i></span>
<input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="Your address" id="R_address"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-street-view" style="font-size:24px"></i></span>
<input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="About yourself and your work" id="R_info"/><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:24px"></i>
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
</div>

<button onclick="myfunction();">Go</button>

     <table id="table" border=1>
   <tr> <th> Name </th> <th> contact </th> <th> license </th><th> email </th><th> state </th><th> city </th></tr>
  
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    jQuery.noConflict();    
    formdata = new FormData();      
    jQuery("#image_to_upload").on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (formdata) {
            formdata.append("image", file);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "destination_ajax_file.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(){}
            });
        }                       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="FILE" id="image_to_upload">
```